# Do I have to stop using Dependency Injection to keep object debug printouts small?

Tags: object-oriented, php, dependency-injection

Say I have a large object - think `EntityManager` of an ORM such as `Doctrine`, or a custom DAO object, or what have you.  Object, output of which is required to be used inside a class, but the object itself could be transient - do its job and then go out of scope.

It does not always matter if such object is large or not, but that it is not necessary to be a part of the class.  However its byproduct is.  Example:

```
//i.e. Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
class BigTerribleDatabaseObject
{
    //300 methods and 20 properties
}
```

**When Not using DI**

`BigTerribleDatabaseObject` is only used to get some data and then it is discarded.

```
class Small
{
    public getData($id)
    {
        $db = new BigTerribleDatabaseObject();
        return $db->getDataById($id);
    }
}
```

**Using DI**

`BigTerribleDatabaseObject` becomes a permanent resident of the small class, despite being injected (it's injected and then it stays).

```
class Small
{
    private $db;
    function __construct(BigTerribleDatabaseObject $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public getData($id)
    {
        $db = $this->db;
        return $db->getDataById($id);
    }
}
```

**My Issue**

I sometimes do a `print_r` statement for debugging purposes on an object.  Like so:

```
//first line depending on whether or not I use DI or not:
$myClass = new Small(new BigTerribleDatabaseObject())
$myClass = new Small()

print_r($myClass);
```

With DI `$myClass` prints contents of `Small` AND also all the content of the `BigTerribleDatabaseObject`, because `BigTerribleDatabaseObject` is part of `Small`.

This floods my screen and sometimes even crashes my browser because in my case it is Doctrine's entity manager and it is huge and unwieldy.

Without DI I get a nice printout of just my very small class.  Which I think is cleaner.

So I have to pick between "nice and small debug printout with no DI" or "use DI but suffer Large and unwieldy debug printout".

**Question**

I much prefer smaller printout.  Does that mean I have to discard using Dependency Injection techniques?  Can I use something else?  Is that a necessary Evil of DI-ing large transient objects?

Comment: While print_r is certainly handy it can produce way too much output in many situations besides the one on your question.  Fortunately, there are several libraries which provide more useful debugging information.  For example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/introduction.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that in your current example, there is not much benefit from passing the object by the caller, since `Small` does not become decoupled from the database. So you should not stop using DI - quite the opposite, you should start to use it correctly.

Instead of injecting the object of class `BigTerribleDatabaseObject`, you could inject a factory method for those kind of objects into `Small` to avoid the need for calling the constructor directly. Or better, the factory could directly encapsulate the database read operation to give your `SmallFootprintInnocentClass` a chance to be tested with a "mock" factory,  with no access to the real database. Something along the lines of

```
class Small
{
    private $myDataFactory;
    function __construct(function $myFactory)
    {
        $this->$myDataFactory = $myFactory;
    }

    public getData($id)
    {
        return $myDataFactory($id);
    }
}
```

(forgive me if I got the syntax wrong, I am not a fluent PHP programmer).

Since the factory will probably have no or minimal internal state, the `print_r` will result in a minimal printout.

Comment: thanks.  What you are suggesting then is just to keep using DI but use a Factory instead exposing the factory but hiding the big object behind it.  Also I have changed my class name to just `Small` realizing that it was too much to read.  Plus, less letters -> easier to spot which one was smaller

Comment: @Dennis You don't have to use factory per se. You can instead to choose the path of fixing the design of your `BigTerribleDatabaseObject`, split it into several smaller, more specific, classes. Still, Doc Brown is right that there's something fundamentally wrong with your current design which is more than ready for refactoring.

Comment: @DavidPacker: I guess the whole point of the question is that `BigTerribleDatabaseObject` might not be easily split into smaller objects (though, if possible, that would probably be a good idea). However, just splitting the big object into smaller ones alone won't decouple the class from the database.

Comment: `BigTerribleDatabaseObject` in my case is Doctrine's EntityManager library class.  Can't change it, it's not mine, but when printing it out is causes much havoc, sometimes flooding the screen with useless to me information, or even breaking the browser for whatever reason (either it is just too big or there is recursion somewhere or a memory leak when trying to print it out)

Comment: @Doc, what do you think of inverting control entirely and have a Factory Method for `Small` instead, where `SmallFactory` instantiates the `Small` object, populates with data gotten via `BigTerribleDatabaseObject`, and then returns a clean lean populated `Small` object to the caller?

Comment: @Dennis: the question you have to ask yourself is: does the class `Small` contain something you want to unit test, decoupled from the database? If yes, you should inject a factory into `Small`. If there is no need to unit test the class, aa the purpose of `Small` might be simply to provide the method `getData`, then a `SmallFactory` might be the better choice.